# What is the meaning of this error, where am I doing wrong? 'targets/Y:0' TensorFlow: Shape error.

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tflearn

I am building a training classifier with my data set. I code the one hot labels with TensorFlow. Append the numpy array image data and one hot label data in training data and then in for testing data. But I am getting a shape error with tensorflow. As a newbie I have tried searching for this and tried to solve it out myself but failed.

**CODE**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as cio
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpg
from random import shuffle
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
import cv2

a = cio.loadmat("D:/compCarsThesisData/data/misc/make_model_name.mat")

images = "D:/compCarsThesisData/data/image/"
IMG_SIZE = 64
MODEL_NAME = 'Classification'
LR = 1e-3

b = a['make_names']
# c = b.reshape(163,)
d = []

for i in range(b.size):
  d.append(b[i][0][0])
  print(d)

labels_dic = {v: k for v, k in enumerate(d)}
print(labels_dic)
indices = np.arange(163)
depth = 163

y = tf.one_hot(indices,depth)
# print(y)

sess = tf.Session()

result = sess.run(y)
print(result)
# labels = []

# labels.append((result,labels_dic))
# print(labels)


 for root, _, files in os.walk(images):
   cdp = os.path.abspath(root)
   for f in files:
     name,ext = os.path.splitext(f)
     if ext == ".jpg":
       cip = os.path.join(cdp,f)
       ci = mpg.imread(cip)
       image = cv2.cv2.resize(ci,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
       image = np.array(image)
       print(image)

 training_data = []
 training_data.append([np.array(image),result])
 print("TrainingData",training_data)
 shuffle(training_data)
 np.save('training_data_with_One_Hot', training_data)
 testing_data = []
 testing_data.append([np.array(image),result])
 print("TestingDATA",testing_data)
 np.save('testing_data_with_One_Hot',testing_data)
 shuffle(testing_data)

#If the data already created First Time
#training_data = np.load('training_data_with_One_Hot.npy')
#testing_data = np.load('testing_data_with_One_Hot.npy')

train = training_data
test = testing_data[-50000:]

X_train = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

y_train = [i[1] for i in train]

X_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
y_test = [i[1] for i in test]
print("YTEST",y_test)



tf.reset_default_graph()
convnet = input_data(shape=[None,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3],name='input')
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')
model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log', tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit({'input': X_train}, {'targets': y_train}, n_epoch=10,
          validation_set=({'input': X_test}, {'targets': y_test}),
          snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

And the error I keep getting is below. Please help.

```
Run id: Classification
Log directory: log/
---------------------------------
Training samples: 1
Validation samples: 1
--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/ThesisWork/seriouswork/classifier_with_onehot.py", line 109, in <module>>
    snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)                       16, in fit
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 216, in fit                                                                        ine 339, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 818, in _trainine 339, in fit
    show_metric)                                                                  on.py", line 929, in run
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 818, in _train                                                                on.py", line 1128, in _run
    feed_batch)
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\sessich has shape '(?, 2)'on.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\zeele\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1128, in _run
    str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 163, 163) for Tensor 'targets/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'
```

Comment: Just an aside, you seem to be pulling your test/validation set directly from your training examples. Your test/validation should always be separate from your training set so that you can properly test if the model is generalizing to unseen data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you specify that `result`, which gets used in `training_data`, has a shape of `(163, 163)`:

```
indices = np.arange(163)
depth = 163
y = tf.one_hot(indices,depth)
result = sess.run(y)
```

While your regression has an output dimension of 2. I am not sure what your intent is by creating 163 one-hot vectors -- are you trying to classify something into 163 dimensions? Either way, the one-hot vector dimensions and output of your regression have to have matching dimensions.

This is the best advice I can give since I am not sure how you intend to generate the labels for your data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and yes I'm trying to classify cars. The names of these cars are in .mat file which are 163 so I made 163 one hot vectors for them. The result I'm using are the labels that I generate. 
As a newbie here, can you give me more explanation, what exactly should I do for it? I'm just a student and trying to learn things this way. How can I change it to matching dimensions

Answer (score 0):

This error means that output shape of your neural network is (None, 2), but here `y_train` you have something with shape (1, 163, 163).

Double check how you create `y_train` and `y_test`. I would start from looking at their shapes.